# What does "…a sight that didn't look better looking back” mean?

Tags: meaning

> I've never seen a sight that didn't look better looking back.

I don't understand this sentence.
What does it mean?

Comment: Hint: the speaker is 'looking back' at the site, What does that mean?

Comment: You MUST tell us where you found this sentence in your question, not in the comments, context will give us a more complete understanding

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I suppose younger folks haven't heard of Lee Marvin?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the only interpretation, but to me it reads like this, with a few implied words added to make it make more sense.

> I've never seen a sight that didn't look better [when I was] looking back [in time at it].

This would mean that when you remember something from your past, you are more likely to forget and/or minimize the bad parts of what you are remembering and more likely to remember and/or emphasize the better parts.

This may not make complete sense because it's not necessarily always true -- for me, seeing Mt. Rushmore in person was far better than reminiscing about seeing it, and the fact that people who suffer traumatic experiences often need therapy certain proves that it's not always the case.  But I can see how it would apply to some situations, such as widows always remembering the good things about their late husbands and forgetting the annoying parts of their personality.